# Keyboard not opening second time in ionic 3 app with ion item

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, keyboard, ionic3, ionic-keyboard

When I clicked on input filed my keyboard does not appear when I tap on input box a second time. And if I put my ion-input outside from ion-item it is working, But in ion item, it is not working.

```
<ion-list class='list' [@flyInBottomSlow]="cloudState">
            <div class="box">
                <ion-item class='input-field'>
                    <ion-label floating >
                        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>Employee Code or Email</ion-label>
                    <ion-input  type="text" [(ngModel)]='username'></ion-input>
                </ion-item>

                <ion-item class='input-field'>
                    <ion-label floating>
                        <i class="fa fa-key"></i>Password</ion-label>
                        <ion-input type="password" [(ngModel)]='password'></ion-input>
                </ion-item>

                <ion-item class='item'>
                    <button ion-button class='button' full (tap)="login()">SUBMIT</button>
                </ion-item>

                <ion-item class="forgot-password">
                    <a (click)="forgotPassword()">Forgot Password?</a>
                </ion-item>
            </div>
            <ion-item class="or_row">
                <span>OR</span>
            </ion-item>

            <ion-item class='item'>
                <button ion-button class='button google' full (tap)="loginWithGoogle()">
                    <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i> LOGIN WITH GOOGLE</button>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
```

When I click on input field I should appear always.

Comment: Which field or input box are you talking about?

Comment: when I try to click on password field then device keyboard not opening.

Comment: What about `Employee Code or Email` field?

Comment: Working fine with "Employee Code or Email field", But in my all pages wherever is put ion-input under ion-item sometimes it appears sometimes not.

Comment: @Sampath: Any solution?

Comment: try to remove <div class="box"> and check whether you are facing the issue.

Comment: @PrithiviRaj: Removed, Not working.

Answer (score 4):

I added disabled false and now it is working. 
Like

```
<ion-item class='input-field'>
                    <ion-label floating>
                        <i class="fa fa-key"></i>Password</ion-label>
                        <ion-input type="password" [(ngModel)]='password' disabled=false></ion-input>
                </ion-item>
```

Note: This is a temporary solution. Hope Ionic team will look into it.